# phonegap to load a page as HTML while the file name is not *.htm?

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to let phonegap-built apps load a page as HTML while the file name is, say, ABC?

Why: on ios `alert()` and `confirm()` shows the file name.  I do not want it show 'index.html'.  If I change my single-page app's file name to my app's name (ABC) then `alert()` and `confirm()` will appear to be showing my app's name.

What I tried: when the file name is ABC, the HTML source is displayed.  It is like in desktop web servers not setting MIME type and the web server serves any page as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

If an app name for an alert title is the goal you need to install the cordova dialogs plugin. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs

Comment: My project started with this very plugin for other reasons (customized look), then saw some problems, which I cannot recall now because it was not me who found them, then looked into the vanilla js approach, and found the file name problem as described.  So I am afraid using plugin is not the answer.

Comment: If you're running into problems with this plugin it is probably an error in your code or architecture. For the record I didn't down vote you.